# How to have infinte pagination in FlatList using hooks in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting the data loaded first time only, but I need infinite pagination using hooks, please let me know how can it be done, currently I am able to fetch data only once and not more than that

```
     import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';
    
    export default function WatchlistClass() {
      const [watchlistData, setData] = useState({data: [], pageNumber: 1});
      useEffect(() => {
        remoteRequest();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, [watchlistData.pageNumber]);
    
      const remoteRequest = () => {
        fetch(`https://abcde/?page=${watchlistData.pageNumber}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: '',
          },
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => {
            setData({...watchlistData, data: [...json.data.reverse()]});
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      };
    
      const loadMore = () => {
        setData({...watchlistData, pageNumber: watchlistData.pageNumber + 1});
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={watchlistData.data}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              return <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              item.id.toString();
            }}
            onEndReached={loadMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Comment: `usePagination` hook may be useful [react-native-flatlist-pagination-hook](https://github.com/ahmedGaber93/react-native-flatlist-pagination-hook#readme)